# JavaScript. Trying to simplify code, maybe with loops?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, chart.js, javascript-objects

I'm very new to coding and I have been playing around with charts.js. I have this function that inserts the data into de chart, but I have to repeat the push method and the if with every array of data, so far there is only two datasets but I plan to add more and I don't want to have to repeat the some code everytime If had 15 datasets. I'm sure there is a simpler way to do it, maybe with a loop, a forEach, with .map? But I don't have enough grasp of javaScript yet to make it work. Some help would be very much apreciated.

This is the function I want to simplify:

```
function add_data(chart, labels, data) {
    var today = new Date();
    var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();

    graficaConexiones.data.datasets[0].data.push(randomData());
    graficaConexiones.data.datasets[1].data.push(randomData());
    graficaConexiones.data.labels.push(time);

    if (graficaConexiones.data.datasets[0].data.length > dataLength) {
        graficaConexiones.data.datasets[0].data.shift();
    }

    if (graficaConexiones.data.datasets[1].data.length > dataLength) {
        graficaConexiones.data.datasets[1].data.shift();
    }

    if (graficaConexiones.data.labels.length > labelLength) {
        graficaConexiones.data.labels.shift()
    }

    graficaConexiones.update();
}
setInterval(add_data, 5000);
```

I tried doing this inside the function, but I got stuck there and have no idea how to continue.

```
    var dataGraph = graficaConexiones.data.datasets

    for (let i = 0; i < dataGraph.length; i++) {
        console.log(dataGraph[i]);
    }
```

This is the complete javascript page:

```
var randomData = function () {
    return Math.round(Math.random() * 10);
};

var dataLength = 10; 
var labelLength = 10;

var today = new Date();
var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();


var ctx = document.getElementById("graficaConexiones");
var graficaConexiones = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
        datasets: [{
                label: "Total conexiones",
                data: [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null],
                borderColor: "#DD0000",
                backgroundColor: "#DD0000",
                fill: false
            },
            {
                label: "Total entrantes",
                data: [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null],
                borderColor: "#1E90FF",
                backgroundColor: "#1E90FF",
                fill: false
            },
        ]
    },
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }]
        },
        title: {
            display: true,
            text: 'Número de conexiones'
        }
    }
});

function add_data(chart, labels, data) {
    var today = new Date();
    var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();

    graficaConexiones.data.datasets[0].data.push(randomData());
    graficaConexiones.data.datasets[1].data.push(randomData());
    graficaConexiones.data.labels.push(time);

    if (graficaConexiones.data.datasets[0].data.length > dataLength) {
        graficaConexiones.data.datasets[0].data.shift();
    }

    if (graficaConexiones.data.datasets[1].data.length > dataLength) {
        graficaConexiones.data.datasets[1].data.shift();
    }

    if (graficaConexiones.data.labels.length > labelLength) {
        graficaConexiones.data.labels.shift()
    }

    graficaConexiones.update();
}
setInterval(add_data, 5000);
```

and the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Conexiones</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <h1>Conexiones</h1>
      <h2>Número de conexiones</h2>

      <canvas id="graficaConexiones" width="1600" height="900"></canvas>
    </div>

    <script src="lineChart.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just `forEach` over the `graficaConexiones.data.datasets` array:

```
graficaConexiones.data.datasets.forEach(({ data }) => {
  data.push(randomData());
  if (data.length > dataLength) {
    data.shift();
  }
});
```

In full:

```
function add_data() {
  const { labels, datasets } = graficaConexiones.data;
  var today = new Date();
  var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
  labels.push(time);
  if (labels.length > labelLength) {
    labels.shift();
  }
  datasets.forEach(({ data }) => {
    data.push(randomData());
    if (data.length > dataLength) {
      data.shift();
    }
  });
}
```

Or, if you're not comfortable with destructuring:

```
function add_data() {
  const labels = graficaConexiones.data.labels;
  const datasets = graficaConexiones.data.datasets;
  var today = new Date();
  var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
  labels.push(time);
  if (labels.length > labelLength) {
    labels.shift();
  }
  datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
    const data = dataset.data;
    data.push(randomData());
    if (data.length > dataLength) {
      data.shift();
    }
  });
}
```

Extracting repeated property accesses into variables first really helps reduce repeated code.

Since you aren't passing any arguments to `add_data`, remove all arguments from its definition.

Comment: Thank you! It works, I'm gonna stick with the second, it's the one that I understand better so far. But I'll keep the other one close. And you're totally right the argument are from previous attempts that I completely forgot to delete.

Answer (score 2):

With async/await the function could be simplified to a loop:

```
  const delay = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));

   function today() {
     const today = new Date();
     return today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
   }

  async function updateLoop() {
    const { datasets, labels } = graficaConexiones.data;

    for(let i = 0; i < Math.Infinity; i++) {
        for(const set of datasets)
           set.data.push(randomData());

        labels.push(today());

        for(const set of [...datasets, labels])
           if(set.length > dataLength) set.shift();

       graficaConexiones.update();
       await delay(500);
   }
 }
```